DirectDraw leak in the DirectX SDK samples?
In the DirectDraw example program 1 that comes with the DirectX 6.1 SDK (file ddex1.cpp), the following C++ code is used in the InitApp function to initialize DirectDraw:
LPDIRECTDRAW                pDD;  <-- local variable declared inside InitApp
...

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Create the main DirectDraw object
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
hRet = DirectDrawCreate(NULL, &pDD, NULL);
if (hRet != DD_OK)
    return InitFail(hWnd, hRet, "DirectDrawCreate FAILED");

// Fetch DirectDraw4 interface
hRet = pDD->QueryInterface(IID_IDirectDraw4, (LPVOID *) & g_pDD);
if (hRet != DD_OK)
    return InitFail(hWnd, hRet, "QueryInterface FAILED");

// Get exclusive mode
hRet = g_pDD->SetCooperativeLevel(hWnd, DDSCL_EXCLUSIVE | DDSCL_FULLSCREEN);
if (hRet != DD_OK)
    return InitFail(hWnd, hRet, "SetCooperativeLevel FAILED");

... other stuff ...

After invoking DirectDrawCreate and storing the returned IDirectDraw interface pointer in the pDD local variable, QueryInterface is invoked on it, to access the DX6.1's new IDirectDraw4 interface. This interface is stored in the global variable g_pDD.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Global data
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
LPDIRECTDRAW4               g_pDD = NULL;        // DirectDraw object
LPDIRECTDRAWSURFACE4        g_pDDSPrimary = NULL;// DirectDraw primary surface
...

In the ReleaseAllObjects cleanup function, Release is invoked on the g_pDD interface pointer.
However, the initial pDD IDirectDraw interface pointer returned by DirectDrawCreate seems lost to me.
According to the COM rules, should Release be called also on the IDirectDraw interface pointer returned by DirectDrawCreate?
In other words, does the sample code leak the initial IDirectDraw interface pointer returned by DirectDrawCreate?
Should the leak be fixed with something like this inside InitApp?
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Create the main DirectDraw object
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
hRet = DirectDrawCreate(NULL, &pDD, NULL);
if (hRet != DD_OK)
    return InitFail(hWnd, hRet, "DirectDrawCreate FAILED");

// Fetch DirectDraw4 interface
hRet = pDD->QueryInterface(IID_IDirectDraw4, (LPVOID *) & g_pDD);
if (hRet != DD_OK)
    return InitFail(hWnd, hRet, "QueryInterface FAILED");

// FIX: Release the previous IDirectDraw interface pointer,
// as we are going to use the new IDirectDraw4 interface from this point on.
pDD->Release();
pDD = NULL;

... Remaining code using IDirectDraw4 via g_pDD ...

// Get exclusive mode
hRet = g_pDD->SetCooperativeLevel(hWnd, DDSCL_EXCLUSIVE | DDSCL_FULLSCREEN);
if (hRet != DD_OK)
    return InitFail(hWnd, hRet, "SetCooperativeLevel FAILED");

...


Or, similarly to the "attached surface" objects, somehow the IDirectDraw interface pointer is "attached" with the IDirectDraw4 interface pointer, so calling Release on the latter automatically releases also the former?
(This is what happens when invoking Release on the g_pDDSPrimary primary surface: it automatically releases also the attached back buffer surface g_pDDSBack.)

Release must be called on every COM object reference you get (from an out parameter or more rarely from a return value), and each reference is supposed to be completely independent from another. That's why today when using C++, one should use smart pointers (like ATL's CComPtr, WRL ComPtr, C++/WinRT, std:: ones, etc.). Where can we find this file so we can have a real look? it's difficult to follow w/o the whole picture.

It seems there is a GitHub repo with the DX6.1 SDK samples here. The basic Direct Draw demos can be found here. The Example Program 1 C++ source code is here.

On calling Release, note that if you use the DDSCAPS_COMPLEX flag, invoking Release only on the primary surface will automatically release all the attached surfaces. In fact that sample code only invokes Release on the primary surface, not on the attached back-buffer surface (which is an output parameter returned by g_pDDSPrimary->GetAttachedSurface).

BTW I do know the COM rules (and smart pointers like ATL::CComPtr): this is why I am asking here about this DirectDraw C++ SDK sample code.

So yes, pDD should be released (for example just after g_pDD has been queried for) like any COM reference. Maybe behind the scene, implementation of dd interfaces is backed by the same class that holds some singleton, so it may not be a real issue in this case, or maybe there was at that time (30y ago) a bug (silently hidden in sample) that caused a crash when you release one interface QI'd for another, like here (I've seen that back then when internally Microsoft didn't use smart pointers like ATL yet), but in the general case it's clearly a reference leak.

Thanks for the confirmation. Considering also the case of attached surfaces, when releasing the root automatically releases all the others, I’m starting thinking that DirectX uses the COM infrastructure (COM interfaces, QueryInterface, etc.) but with its own non-standard rules.

The COM that DirectDraw (and DirectX after that) use is sometimes referred to as "nano COM" or "lightweight COM". It means it just has IUnknown, references and QI, and that's it (no registry, no apartment, no type libs, no marshaling, no out-of-process, no DCOM, etc.) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com but what you describe is not that, if releasing an interface releases others, it's more a bug that you must obviously work around, will never be fixed

What you call a bug is well documented behavior in the DDSCAPS_COMPLEX flag, as already written above. However, this doesn’t follow the standard COM rules of reference counting and calling Release.
